# mulesoft http endpoint to retrieve xml feed and display

Tags: xml, http, mule, esb, custom-headers

I've fairly new to Mule ESB. I've a simple use case where I need to point to an http endpoint, pass in a string to retrieve a list of users, pass userid, partner id via the header and retrieve an xml response and display it. What is the best way to do this in Mule and what components would I need to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem failry new to Mule and Stackoverflow. Do some research before coming to the community for help. That way you can ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding of your scenario you can create a REST service with Mule Jersey.

For this you need basic unsderstanding of Mule Flow, Mule Components and Jersey.

Refer to the following links for more information and some examples

http://www.javaroots.com/2013/04/creating-rest-service-using-mule-esb-33.html

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/REST+Component+Reference

http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-rest-service-using

Hope this helps.